# How to Store Text with hyperlink inside base on User Input in Textfield PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a Problem when user ask me to create a input textarea form that could handle copy paste lots of wording at the ms word file and save them to mysql database, so that text could be displayed at website page blogpost, so i manage to create them text area input form. but there is a problem, sometimes the wording has a hyperlink inside it, and the hyperlink could not be clicked at the web page blogpost. how to make this works

i am a newbie here

Example :
I want to copy this word at ms Office
[image]

i want to save this hyperlink on to the mysql database, but user can only save it using our form input system, now we are using textarea input form3

```
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

i know its leads to raw text going to the database, but i need solution to make the links still clickable when it appears in the web page blog post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/) on your textarea, this will handle your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it is open a way to solving my problem